# How to concat two Pandas dataframes that have the same columns but only if the value of one column in both dataframes is the same?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes like the below:

DF1:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | yes |
| 22 | no |
| 24 | yes |
| 22 | no |
| 27 | no |

DF2:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 28 | yes |
| 22 | no |
| 29 | yes |
| 22 | yes |
| 27 | yes |

I want to concat both dataframes, so that I end up with the below. I don't want to join the dataframes on col1, as that doubles the number of columns. I just want to combine the dataframe vertically if they share a common value on "col1." Any help on this?

DF3:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | yes |
| 22 | no |
| 22 | no |
| 22 | no |
| 22 | yes |
| 27 | no |
| 27 | yes |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us first find the common values using set intersection then concat the required rows from `df1` and `df2` and optionally sort the values

```
i = set(df1['col1']) & set(df2['col1'])
pd.concat([df1[df1['col1'].isin(i)], df2[df2['col1'].isin(i)]]).sort_values('col1')
```

---

```
   col1 col2
0    22  yes
1    22   no
3    22   no
1    22   no
3    22  yes
4    27   no
4    27  yes
```

Comment: The set conversion may not be strictly necessary, based on the sample data provided my timings were almost identical just doing doing the work in the `isin()` with `[df1[df1['col1'].isin(df2['col1'])],df2[df2['col1'].isin(df1['col1'])]]`. That said, I'm guessing your answer scales up better with larger dataframes, +1 from me